# How to normalize filenames listed in a range

Tags: vba, excel, format, excel-2010

I have a list of filenames in a spreadsheet in the form of "Smith, J. 010112.pdf". However, they're in the varying formats of "010112.pdf", "01.01.12.pdf", and "1.01.2012.pdf". How could I change these to one format of "010112.pdf"?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Personally I hate using VBA where worksheet functions will work, so I've worked out a way to do this with worksheet functions. Although you could cram this all into one cell, I've broken it out into a lot of independent steps in separate columns so you can see how it's working, step by step.

For simplicity I'm assuming your file name is in A1

**B1** =LEN(A1)
*determine the length of the filename*

**C1** =SUBSTITUTE(A1," ","")
*replace spaces with nothing*

**D1** =LEN(C1)
*see how long the string is if you replace spaces with nothing*

**E1** =B1-D1
*determine how many spaces there are*

**F1** =SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",CHAR(8),E1)
*replace the last space with a special character that can't occur in a file name*

**G1** =SEARCH(CHAR(8), F1)
*find the special character. Now we know where the last space is*

**H1** =LEFT(A1,G1-1)
*peel off everything before the last space*

**I1** =MID(A1,G1+1,255)
*peel off everything after the last space*

**J1** =FIND(".",I1)
*find the first dot*

**K1** =FIND(".",I1,J1+1)
*find the second dot*

**L1** =FIND(".",I1,K1+1)
*find the third dot*

**M1** =MID(I1,1,J1-1)
*find the first number*

**N1** =MID(I1,J1+1,K1-J1-1)
*find the second number*

**O1** =MID(I1,K1+1,L1-K1-1)
*find the third number*

**P1** =TEXT(M1,"00")
*pad the first number*

**Q1** =TEXT(N1,"00")
*pad the second number*

**R1** =TEXT(O1,"00")
*pad the third number*

**S1** =IF(ISERR(K1),M1,P1&Q1&R1)
*put the numbers together*

**T1** =H1&" "&S1&".pdf"
*put it all together*

It's kind of a mess because Excel hasn't added a single new string manipulation function in over 20 years, so things that should be easy (like "find last space") require severe trickery.

Comment: +1 for correctness, but whether it works or not, I find highly complicated formulas to be more cumbersome than VBA to me, especially if you've made a mistake. You yourself call it *severe trickery*, which should say something about the process. ;-)

Comment: If anyone is curious what this looks like in a single-cell formula: http://pastebin.com/tUKcjyM1

Comment: Yeah, to be honest, VBA is more straightforward in this particular example. Still, there's a lot to learn from figuring out the worksheet way to do things which often makes for much more robust spreadsheets.

Comment: @JoelSpolsky I agree; having both in your toolset can be a great asset.

Comment: I just threw up a bit in my mouth. I don't know whether to upvote or downvote this! (or flag as offensive)

Comment: This is beautiful. Thank you. I love you.

Comment: You're working harder than you need to since worksheet functions lack string processing functionality - if you don't want to use VBA this could be done with just a few Excel commands. `a`) Edit Replace twice:[.pdf]->[] then [* ]->['] `b`) Text to columns|Fixed Width|Next|Date:DMY `c`) Format cells: ddmmyy.p\df. (If you then want to convert the cell formats to text just copy and paste from office clipboard or notepad)

Comment: @lori_m you should propose that as an answer and I'll upvote it

Comment: @JoelSpolsky I've added a slight variation on the method below - if it needs repeating a UDF would surely be the way to go.

Answer (score 7):

Here's a screenshot of a simple four-step method based on Excel commands and formulas, as suggested in a comment to the answered post (with a few changes)...

[image]

Comment: Your date format in col D doesn't seem to to fit the MDY you have labeled in D2 (looks more like DMY, base on D7 to me), though the final output is still right.

Comment: I did actually choose the MDY option for Column D but it is formatted d/m/yy by default because that's the default short date format for my European settings.

Answer (score 6):

This function below works. I've assumed that the date is in `ddmmyy` format, but adjust as appropriate if it's `mmddyy` -- I can't tell from your example.

```
Function FormatThis(str As String) As String

    Dim strDate As String
    Dim iDateStart As Long
    Dim iDateEnd As Long
    Dim temp As Variant

    ' Pick out the date part
    iDateStart = GetFirstNumPosition(str, False)
    iDateEnd = GetFirstNumPosition(str, True)
    strDate = Mid(str, iDateStart, iDateEnd - iDateStart + 1)

    If InStr(strDate, ".") <> 0 Then
        ' Deal with the dot delimiters in the date
        temp = Split(strDate, ".")
        strDate = Format(DateSerial( _
            CInt(temp(2)), CInt(temp(1)), CInt(temp(0))), "ddmmyy")
    Else
        ' No dot delimiters... assume date is already formatted as ddmmyy
        ' Do nothing
    End If

    ' Piece it together
    FormatThis = Left(str, iDateStart - 1) _
        & strDate & Right(str, Len(str) - iDateEnd)
End Function
```

This uses the following helper function:

```
Function GetFirstNumPosition(str As String, startFromRight As Boolean) As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim startIndex As Long
    Dim endIndex As Long
    Dim indexStep As Integer

    If startFromRight Then
        startIndex = Len(str)
        endIndex = 1
        indexStep = -1
    Else
        startIndex = 1
        endIndex = Len(str)
        indexStep = 1
    End If

    For i = startIndex To endIndex Step indexStep
        If Mid(str, i, 1) Like "[0-9]" Then
            GetFirstNumPosition = i
            Exit For
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

To test:

```
Sub tester()

    MsgBox FormatThis("Smith, J. 01.03.12.pdf")
    MsgBox FormatThis("Smith, J. 010312.pdf")
    MsgBox FormatThis("Smith, J. 1.03.12.pdf")
    MsgBox FormatThis("Smith, J. 1.3.12.pdf")

End Sub
```

They all return `"Smith, J. 010312.pdf"`.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need VBA. Start by replacing the "."s with nothing:

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(A1,".","")
```

This will change the ".PDF" to "PDF", so let's put that back:

```
 =SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",""),"pdf",".pdf")
```

Comment: This works, but I still have a period after the FirstName initial. How would I get this to skip that period?

Comment: Also, this doesn't take care of the issue with the "1.01.2012"

Comment: Do you always have a space before the numeric date part?

Comment: Yes, there is a always a space

Answer (score 1):

### DISCLAIMER:

**As @Jean-FrançoisCorbett has mentioned, this does not work for `"Smith, J. 1.01.12.pdf"`. Instead of reworking this completely, I'd recommend his solution!**

```
Option Explicit

Function ExtractNumerals(Original As String) As String
'Pass everything up to and including ".pdf", then concatenate the result of this function with ".pdf". 
'This will not return the ".pdf" if passed, which is generally not my ideal solution, but it's a simpler form that still should get the job done. 
'If you have varying extensions, then look at the code of the test sub as a guide for how to compensate for the truncation this function creates.
Dim i As Integer
Dim bFoundFirstNum As Boolean

    For i = 1 To Len(Original)
        If IsNumeric(Mid(Original, i, 1)) Then
            bFoundFirstNum = True
            ExtractNumerals = ExtractNumerals & Mid(Original, i, 1)
        ElseIf Not bFoundFirstNum Then
            ExtractNumerals = ExtractNumerals & Mid(Original, i, 1)
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```

I used this as a testcase, which does not correctly cover all your examples:

```
Sub test()

MsgBox ExtractNumerals("Smith, J. 010112.pdf") & ".pdf"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Got awk? Get the data into a text file, and

```
awk -F'.' '{ if(/[0-9]+\.[0-9]+\.[0-9]+/) printf("%s., %02d%02d%02d.pdf\n", $1, $2, $3, length($4) > 2 ? substr($4,3,2) : $4); else print $0; }' your_text_file
```

Assuming the data are exactly as what you described, e.g.,

Smith, J. 010112.pdf
Mit, H. 01.02.12.pdf
Excel, M. 8.1.1989.pdf
Lec, X. 06.28.2012.pdf